# Retorno da janela "Salvar como"

Tags: php

Boa tarde,estou usando esta rotina para forçar um download com php

```
require_once 'PHPWord.php';
require_once 'PHPWord/Template.php';
$PHPWord = new PHPWord(); 
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('models/Mod.docx');
$document->setValue('NOTA_TECNICA',ex01457); 
$document->setValue('NUM',ex16050);
$document->setValue('FUNCIONARIO_01','exFuncionario');

$nomefile="ex01457"."_"."exFuncionario";
$nota="ofi/NT".$nomefile.".docx";
$document->save($nota);

// Fazendo download do arquivo
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$nota);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($nota));
flush();

readfile($nota);
unlink($nota); // deletes the temporary file

//Fim do download 
unset($template);
```

Quando o usuário faz o download abre a janela "Salvar como"

Tem como saber se o usuário salvou o arquivo? Nesta janela o usuário tem a opção "Salvar" ou "Cancelar". Tem como eu saber qual ação o usuário tomou? Através da resposta irei criar uma rotina para salvar no banco de dados, juntamente com o login do usuário.

PS: Estou usando o PHP versão 5.3.5, testando localmente com o Wamp no Windows 10.

Obriado,
Thiago P.

Comment: Eu não acho que há uma maneira de descobrir isso porque o processo de download é totalmente tratada no lado do cliente / navegador.